# Spring managed StatementInspector

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

How can I create a "Spring managed" [StatementInspector](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/resource/jdbc/spi/StatementInspector.html) to enable certain Springboot functionality like `Autowiring` classes and referencing spring properties via `@Value` within the `StatementInspector` class.

The current method I use to register a StatementInspector via a configuration property (below) does not allow for these Spring functionalities.

```
spring:
 jpa:
  properties:
   hibernate:
    session_factory:
      statement_inspector: x.x.SqlStatementInspector
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution:

1. Configure a [`HibernatePropertiesCustomizer`-bean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernatePropertiesCustomizer.html)

```java
@Bean
public HibernatePropertiesCustomizer hibernateCustomizer(StatementInspector statementInspector) {
    return (properties) -> properties.put(AvailableSettings.STATEMENT_INSPECTOR, statementInspector);
}
```

2. Provide a or more [conditional](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnProperty.html) `StatementInspector`-beans based on a property value.

*example*: ***OneStatementInspector** is only created when **demo.statement_inspector** is equal to **one***

```java
@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "demo", name ="statement_inspector", havingValue = "one" )
public class OneStatementInspector implements StatementInspector {
    
   @Value("${demo.my-value}") String myValue; 

    @Override
    public String inspect(String s) {
        // myValue is available here
        ...
    }

}
```

*application.properties*

```
demo.my-value=my autowired value
demo.statement_inspector = one
```

3. If the configuration of a `StatementInspector` is optional ( demo.statement_inspector is not mandatory) there are multiple options:

- Make one of the possible `StatementInspector` the default (match if property is missing) `@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "demo", name ="statement_inspector", havingValue = "...", matchIfMissing = true )`
- Make `HibernatePropertiesCustomizer`-bean optional:

```java
@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty("demo.statement_inspector")
public HibernatePropertiesCustomizer hibernateCustomizer(StatementInspector statementInspector) {
    ...
}
```

- Provide a default bean as @dekkard suggests:

```java
@Bean   
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(StatementInspector.class)     
public StatementInspector emptyInspector() {        
  return EmptyStatementInspector.INSTANCE;  
}
```

**note:** No need to set `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.session_factory.statement_inspector`

Comment: That's a clever solution. One thing to note is that there should be a fallback in case the property is not set. E.g. 
`@Bean
 @ConditionalOnMissingBean(StatementInspector.class)
 public StatementInspector emptyInspector() {
  return EmptyStatementInspector.INSTANCE;
 }`

Comment: @dekkard Good point! Alternatively one could use `@ConditionalOnProperty(.... matchIfMissing=true)` on one of the provided `StatementInspector`.